# What could be the reason behind the failure of the task?

Tags: c#, azure, async-await, task, azure-table-storage

I have a class named `TableStorageController.cs`

```
public class TableStorageController
{
    private static Dictionary<string, BlockingCollection<CloudModelDetail>> s_dictionary = new Dictionary<string, BlockingCollection<CloudModelDetail>>();
    private static StorageAccount s_azureStorageAccount;
    private readonly CloudModelDetail _cloudModelDetail;
    private static CancellationTokenSource s_cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private static int s_retailerId;

    /// <summary>
    /// Static task to log transactions to Azure Table Storage after every 5 minutes.
    /// </summary>
    static TableStorageController()
    {
        try
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(300000, s_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
                    foreach (var retaileridkey in s_dictionary.Keys)
                    {
                        var batchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();
                        while (s_dictionary[retaileridkey].Count != 0 && batchOperation.Count < 101)
                        {
                            batchOperation.InsertOrMerge(s_dictionary[retaileridkey].Take());
                        }
                        if (batchOperation?.Count != 0)
                            await s_azureStorageAccount.VerifyCloudTable.ExecuteBatchAsync(batchOperation);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            s_log.Fatal("Azure task run failed", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This task is meant to run after every 5 minutes and log whatever items are present in the dictionary to Azure Table Storage.
Locally when I run my code, I can see it gets triggered after every 5 minutes.
But, somehow once after the deployment in another environment (Production), it fails.

Can anyone point out what am I missing?

**Note**: I have never got an exception `Azure task run failed`.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the exception handling *inside* the `Task.Run` block. You do not await the call to Task.Run so exceptions will go unnoticed. And since `await Task.Delay` is already non-blocking I do not see why you need the extra Task for. Try this:

```
static async void TableStorageController()
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), s_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            foreach (var retaileridkey in s_dictionary.Keys)
            {
                var batchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();
                while (s_dictionary[retaileridkey].Count != 0 && batchOperation.Count < 101)
                {
                    batchOperation.InsertOrMerge(s_dictionary[retaileridkey].Take());
                }
                if (batchOperation?.Count != 0)
                    await s_azureStorageAccount.VerifyCloudTable.ExecuteBatchAsync(batchOperation);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        s_log.Fatal("Azure task run failed", ex);
    }
}
```

By the way, you could also use a timer instead of a `Task.Delay` with a CancellationToken